# How can I disable Photos on my iPad 2?

Tags: ipad

I want to disable photos icon in my iPad 2, but I don't know how to do that. I want to disable like Movies. I can disable Movies in General's Restriction, but I can't find how to disable Photos.
How can I do this?

Comment: see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15138/is-it-possible-to-set-restrictions-on-any-ios-app/15150#15150

Comment: Ditto what @user6124 said.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in support for disabling specific apps on iOS. However, there is a specific software for this (and costs $$$), but requires jailbreaking.

Currently the best way to jailbreak an iPad 2 is through [JailbreakMe](http://www.jailbreakme.com//). It is really simple, just launch it in Safari and follow the steps.

After installing, launch Cydia. Navigate to the Cydia Store and purchase [iProtect](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/iprotect). After purchasing and activating it you should be able to "lock" your individual apps, such as the Photos application.

Comment: For free using SBSettings you can hide the icon.

Comment: @mankoff: the OP wants the app disabled.

Comment: Correct. If you can't launch it, isn't it disabled? You solution was for locking, not disabling, technically.